# Numerical evaluation after Normal?

Tags: replacement, numerical-value

I'm interested in numerical evaluation thru substitution:

```
a /. a -> 1
(*=> 1 *)
```

However if I used `Normal` in the "pipe" — it doesn't work:

```
a // Normal /. a -> 1
(*=> a *)
```

How do I get numerical estimation after `Normal`?

Here's a real world example:

```
Sin[a] // Series[#, {a, 0, 3}] & // Normal /. a -> 1
```

**Edit**

The solution provided by the [ilian in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144482/numerical-evaluation-after-normal?noredirect=1#comment388514_144482) works:

```
a // Normal // ReplaceAll[a -> 1]
(*=> 1 *)
```

Comment: `(a // Normal) /. a -> 1`

Comment: @ilian: it works, but defeats the coolness of pipes.

Comment: It's a matter of precedence. But if you want to have a chain of postfix operations, try `a // Normal // ReplaceAll[a -> 1]`.

Comment: @ilian amusingly, this is undocumented syntax that also gets a complaint from the syntax highlighter. Works as expected, though.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP That may depend on the version, but the operator form of `ReplaceAll` is documented.

Comment: @ilian Perhaps not in 10.2, at least not in the details section,where it usually is for Select and friends